# How to loop for Structures?

Tags: c, loops, data-structures

loops for structures

```
main() 
{
    structure perdata //MADE A STRUCTURE
    {
     char name;
     int age;
     float salary;
    }p1,p2,p3;
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
     printf("p%d.name",i);
     scanf("%s",);/*should loop and read names of p1,p2,p3*/
    }
printf("p1.name:%s",p1.name);
getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always make arrays of structures, classes etc. whenever you need to loop through instances.

```
   int main(void) 
    {
        struct perdata //MADE A STRUCTURE
        {
         char name[20];
         int age;
         float salary;
        };

        struct perdata p[4];

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
         //printf("p%d.name",i);
         scanf("%s", &p[i].name);/*should loop and read names of p1,p2,p3*/
        }

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
           printf("p%d.name:%s\n",i+1, p[i].name);
        }
    getch();

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **array of structures** so that you may iterate through it.

Example : An array of student structure,

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student{
    char name[50];
    int roll;
    float marks;
};

int main(){
    struct student s[10]; //Ten student details maybe stored
    int i;
    printf("Enter information of students:\n");

    //get the details of 10 students
    for(i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        s[i].roll=i+1;
        printf("\nFor roll number %d\n",s[i].roll);
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s",s[i].name);
        printf("Enter marks: ");
        scanf("%f",&s[i].marks);
        printf("\n");
    }

    //display the details of 10 students
    printf("Displaying information of students:\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
     printf("\nInformation for roll number %d:\n",i+1);
     printf("Name: ");
     puts(s[i].name);
     printf("Marks: %.1f",s[i].marks);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Use the above sample code & write your program.